# State of NSMenuItem bound to boolean in NSUserDefaults not staying in sync

Tags: nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings, nsmenuitem

I have an NSMenuItem titled "Word Wrap" in my main menu (MainMenu.xib). Its value is bound to my shared user defaults controller, also instantiated in the XIB. It also sends the following action when selected:

```
- (IBAction)toggleWordWrap:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaultsController *ctrlr = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
    if ([[[ctrlr values] valueForKey:@"wordWrapIsEnabled"] boolValue]) {
        // turn on word wrap
    } else {
        // turn off word wrap
    }
}
```

In my app delegate's `+initialize` method, I populate the standard user defaults with default values:

```
+ (void)initializeDefaults {
    NSDictionary *defaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"wordWrapIsEnabled",
                             // etc.
                             nil];
    NSUserDefaultsController *ctrlr = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
    [ctrlr setInitialValues:defaults];
}
```

My problem is that my NSMenuItem's state is not staying in sync with my user defaults. Here is a timeline of what happens:

**App launch:**

- Word Wrap menu item not checked
- `wordWrapIsEnabled` is NO
- Word wrap is OFF

**1st time Word Wrap is selected:**

- Word Wrap menu item checked
- `wordWrapIsEnabled` is NO *(BZZZT WRONG)*
- Word wrap is OFF *(BZZZT WRONG)*

**2nd time Word Wrap is selected:**

- Word Wrap menu item not checked
- `wordWrapIsEnabled` is YES *(BZZZT WRONG)*
- Word Wrap is ON *(BZZZT WRONG)*

Repeat flip-flop ad infinitum.

I've checked to make sure there is nothing else in my project that accesses `wordWrapIsEnabled`. Could there be a race condition between the invocation of the selector and the setting of `wordWrapIsEnabled` via the binding? I've been assuming that the bound value gets set first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you click a menu item with a bound `state` (or `value`) property, the menu item both triggers its action *and* flips the bound value. And the order of these two operations does not seem to be guaranteed, see the following [thread on Cocoa Builder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/211373-how-to-deal-with-menuitem-with-both-binded-state-property-and-an-action-method.html):

> Thanks, I am not absolutely sure
>   because I did several changes in my
>   project but I think that this can be
>   considered a bug of 10.5 sdk, because
>   it started to happen when I  started
>   to compile for it. The (almost) same
>   project when it was targeted for Tiger
>   always changed the bound value
>   *before* the target-action was executed, regardless if it was a
>   button or a menuItem. Apparently this
>   consistency has been broken in
>   Leopard. I may post a bug report after
>   some testing to confirm it.

There’s also a related [Radar bug report](http://openradar.appspot.com/7903888) saying that menu items should not flip the bound value automatically. This is probably too late as an answer to your question, but hopefully will help next time somebody runs into this issue.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. I would never in a million years have guessed that the state was being flipped automatically.

Comment: Doh! I tested plenty ways to toggle the value properly before finding this. Sometimes increased laziness prevents from writing nonsense code ;)

Answer (score 2):

When you're using Cocoa bindings to Shared User Defaults for a NSMenuItem, you should stop using the selector for the NSMenuItem and instead use key-value observing to determine when the value has changed and then act appropriately.

In this example, I've got a `useTransparency` value name that an NSMenuItem is bound to. In my controller's init, I register to receive updates to this value:

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userDefaults addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"useTransparency"
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:NULL];
```

Then later I implement the observer method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"KVO: %@ changed property %@ to value %@", object, keyPath, change);

    if ([keyPath compare:@"useTransparency"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        BOOL isTransparent = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] boolValue];
        [self setTransparency:isTransparent];
    }
}
```

In particular, I do not bind a selector for the NSMenuItem at all - I just let key-value observing do the job. If you bind to the selector, you run into the problem of trying to guess when the value will change versus the selector being fired off. Avoid that whole problem completely by just using the bindings system rather than a mix of the two.